# Which statistical test can you use to compare the % frequency of a selection of 1 of 3 options (feeding locations) from 2 groups:adults vs. juveniles?

Tags: percentage

I am trying to compare how often members from two groups of turtles (adults vs juveniles), fed in 1 of 3 locations (sea floor, free-floating, or surface).

I don't think I can use a chi-squared or Fisher's as the turtles could have fed in multiple locations in the same 'test'.e.g 10 times on the sea floor, 2 times in free floating, and 0 at the surface.

So far, I have come the the conclusion that I can maybe work out the % frequency for each of the 3 locations for each group (adults n=9 vs juveniles n=5).  Is there a test that would allow me to do this?

Alternatively, is it possible to work out the % frequency for each turtle (so each turtle had a total of 100% of their feeding events recorded across all 3 locations), and then perhaps compared the groups in a rank sum test and see if their was any relationship between the groups this way?

Or is this possible with chi-square/ Fishers?  Many thanks

Comment: Fisher's exact test can be applied here. You have a 2x3 contingency table, and Fisher's test tells you whether the adult and juvenile are significantly different.

Comment: Hi and thank you for the feedback. Is it still statistically valid to use the 'raw counts' for each time they were recorded feeding in a particular location when each of the turtles was potential feeding in all three of the locations in the same test?  As opposed to a percentage frequency for each group together.  I have seen that a chi-squared should only be used on raw counts and not percentages before you compute the statistic.  But I have also not been able to find any example where they do not have a mutually exclusive 'choice' from the predictor variable.

Comment: I.e. they can only choose one of the options of the dependent variable levels...Is the chi-squared or Fishers ok for a percentage frequency analysis of difference between two groups?